# Laravel Relationship Property Does Not Exist In This Collection Instance

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```php
$category = Category::orderBy('category_name_en', 'ASC')
->get();

$subcategory = SubCategory::where('category_id', $category->id)
->orderBy('subcategory_name_en', 'ASC')
->get();

$subsubcategory = SubSubCategory::where('subcategory_id', $subcategory->id)
->orderBy('subsubcategory_name_en', 'ASC')
->get();

return view('welcome', compact('category', 'subcategory', 'subsubcategory'));
```

In this above code we are getting error:

> Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

Why is this error showing?

Comment: `$category` is a Collection, not a single `Category` instance. You can't do `$category->id`, you need to iterate.

Comment: Also, this question is asked every day on Stackoverflow, do a Google search for "trying to get property of non-object :stackoverflow" and you'll find lots of solutions to your problem.

Comment: You could do it like in @JustCarty's answer but since you're talking about relationships, why aren't you using them as they are intended? If you set them up properly, you should be able to do this: `return view('welcome', [ 'category' => 'category', 'subcategories' => $category->subcategories, 'subsubcategories' => $category->subcategories->map->subcategories->flatten()));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are returning a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections) whenever you write `get`.

Try this instead:

```php
$category = Category::orderBy('category_name_en', 'ASC')
->get();

$subcategory = SubCategory::whereIn('category_id', $category->pluck('id'))
->orderBy('subcategory_name_en', 'ASC')
->get();

$subsubcategory = SubSubCategory::whereIn('subcategory_id', $subcategory->pluck('id'))
->orderBy('subsubcategory_name_en', 'ASC')
->get();

return view('welcome', compact('category', 'subcategory', 'subsubcategory'));
```

The changes being `where` converted to [`whereIn`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-wherein), and `->id` becomes [`->pluck('id')`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck).

As you can see from the documentation, `whereIn` accepts an array of values for it's second argument, and `pluck` will return an array of, in our case, IDs.
Combining these will mean that `category_id` will need to exist within the array.

---

If, however, these models were supposed to supply a single Model.
Then you should do the following:

```php
$category = Category::orderBy('category_name_en', 'ASC')
->first();

$subcategory = SubCategory::where('category_id', $category->id)
->orderBy('subcategory_name_en', 'ASC')
->first();

$subsubcategory = SubSubCategory::where('subcategory_id', $subcategory->id)
->orderBy('subsubcategory_name_en', 'ASC')
->first();

return view('welcome', compact('category', 'subcategory', 'subsubcategory'));
```

This is using the [`first`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-first) method to return a single instance.

Comment: Attempt to read property "subsubcategory_name_en" on bool

Comment: Its not work perfectly because they are get all data not specifically .. actually they are not perform conditional match with id