# Property [ID] does not exist on this collection instance. Laravel Form error

Tags: php, laravel, forms, properties

Alright so, for my school project I have to delete a container out of my database. I've made forms before that would delete rows but this time i'm running into a error that I cannot resolve.
I've gone through many posts on multiple forums but at this point I'm raging non stop cuz there seems to be no fix

Error: Property [ID] does not exist on this collection instance.

index.blade.php ->

```
<form action="{{ route('container.destroy',$container->ID) }}" action="POST">
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <button type="submit" title="Delete Post">Delete</button>
</form>
```

web.php ->

```
Route::resource('container',App\Http\Controllers\containerController::class);
```

containerController.php ->

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $container = Container::all();

        return view('container.index')->with('container',$container);
    }

public function destroy($id)
    {
        $container = Container::find($id);
        $container->delete();
        return redirect('container')->with('status', 'Container is Opgehaald');
    }
```

The model is Container and has the following tables:

```
ID
ContainerPortal
PlaatsAvailable
Herkomst
Bestemming
VervoerderAankomst
VervoerderVertrek
OphaalDatum
Move0
Move1
Move2
Move3
Move4
Move5
updated_at
created_at
```

index.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

<h3 class="text-center p-4 fontOne">Alle Containers</h3>
<a href="/run" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-block p-3 fontOne" style="margin: 0 auto; display:block;">Voeg Extra Container toe</a>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th scope="col">Container</th>
    <th scope="col">Portal</th>
    <th scope="col">Herkomst</th>
    <th scope="col">Bestemming</th>
    <th scope="col">Ophaal Datum</th>
    <th scope="col">Delete</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@if(!$containers)
    <p>Kon geen containers vinden</p>
@else
    @foreach($containers as $container)
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Container: {{$container->ID}}</th>
                    <td>Container Portal: {{$container->ContainerPortal}}</td>
                    <td>Herkomst: {{$container->Herkomst}}</td>
                    <td>Bestemming: {{$container->Bestemming}}</td>
                    <td>Ophaal Datum: {{$container->OphaalDatum}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <form action="{{ route('container.destroy',$container->ID) }}" action="POST">
                            {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <button type="submit" title="Delete Post">Delete</button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
    @endforeach
@endif
</tbody>
</table>
@endsection
```

Tried multiple solutions from stack overflow and other forums, I'm working with the most updated Laravel so I don't know what the issue could be

`Update`
After using my brain properly I saw a typo in the form, it was action="POST" instead of method="POST"

Comment: `$container` is a Collection, not a single record. You probably defined it use `::all()`, or `->get()` instead of `->first()`, but you didn't show the Controller method that defines it. Also, this has been asked a bunch of times on Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70030106/property-id-does-not-exist-on-this-collection-instance, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63219872/property-role-does-not-exist-on-this-collection-instance, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67638492/laravel-relationship-property-does-not-exist-in-this-collection-instance, etc.

Comment: (Sorry, linked the wrong duplicate) If you could [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75020551/edit) and show the Controller method that returns your `index.blade.php` view, and how you're defining `$container`, then we can give you a clearer answer.

Comment: Off the record: use named routes with parameters in your action instead of `url()`. Add your controller code for the index function. my guess is the form is inside a foreach loop? What does the `@foreach()` look like?

Comment: here's the index function from containerController:
```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $container = Container::all();

        return view('container.index')->with('container',$container);
    }
```

Comment: Bingo; `$container = Container::all();`. So you can't do `$container->ID`, since you have multiple `Container` instances. You need to do some kind of loop, like `@foreach($container as $cont)`, then `$cont->ID` would be available. Also, `$containers` is a better variable name, since `::all()` returns multiple.

Comment: Also, never do `@foreach($container as $container)`; you're using the same variable inside and outside the loop; that's never a good idea as it can cause unintended side-effects like the one you're experiencing now. `@foreach($container as $cont)`, or rename the variable as I suggested, `$containers = Container::all()`, then `->with('containers', $containers)`, then `@foreach($containers as $container)`.

Comment: that has been changed but I'm still on the error :/

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

in your web.php not need define this line:

```
Route::get("container/{id}",[App\Http\Controllers\containerController::class, 'destroy']);
```

for solve problem need to pass container to your blade, for this you should write this code in your `containerController` action `edit`/`show` (which one use in your project):

```php
 public function edit($id)
    {
        $container = YOUR_MODEL_NAME::find($id);
        
        return view('YOUR_VIEW_NAME', compact('container'));
    }
```

in your blade change form like bellow:

```html
    @foreach($container as $container_item)
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Container: {{$container_item->ID}}</th>
            <td>Container Portal: {{$container_item->ContainerPortal}}</td>
            <td>Herkomst: {{$container_item->Herkomst}}</td>
            <td>Bestemming: {{$container_item->Bestemming}}</td>
            <td>Ophaal Datum: {{$container_item->OphaalDatum}}</td>
            <td>
                <form action="{{ route('container.destroy',$container_item->ID) }}" action="POST">
                    @method('DELETE')
                    @csrf
                    <button type="submit" title="Delete Post">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

and i think everything work very well.

also for getting more information, can read laravel document

[Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#resource-controllers)

and for view defined route run this command

```bash
php artisan route:list
```

Comment: sadly the error is still there, removed the extra Route::get row. it wont land in the controller at all from what I can see, it sends me to the follow address with the same error: http://127.0.0.1:8000/container/1?_method=DELETE&_token=JzUUwk1ih6APlz4p8o5ul8OxowjPQXBtcuhFJ6Ff

Comment: @Riendejong i see your index file, your foreach loop is incorrect,
    @foreach($container as $item) , use like this, your collection name should not equal you item!!

Comment: @Riendejong update my answer, change your blade file

Answer (score 0):

You are passing $container in index function, not $containers...

change like below :

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $containers = Container::all();

        return view('container.index')
            ->with('containers',$containers);
    }
```